# List files by using UNIX/Linux commands pipes and redirection

Tags: linux, pipe

"By using UNIX/Linux commands, pipes (“|”) and redirections (“>”, “>>”)
make a listing of all processes that you are currently running in your
UNIX/Linux distribution, sorted by the command name in alphabetical order
(i.e. “a” first)"

This is the question I am trying to awnser. I think I am almost there, but I am having som trouble with sorting it alphabetically. 
The code I used was "ps aux | less". This listed it out neatly, but not alphabetically. I tried with sort aswell, but I don't know how to do that.
I tried "ps aux | less | sort" but then it was hard to see what I actually listed.

Comment: Do the sorting before the "presentation" of the output, `ps aux | sort | less`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
ps -fea | sort -k 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
ps aux --sort cmd
```